# how to open a file in vscode through a terminal?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I want to open a project folder using terminal.
when type the command `.code` in terminal it open up vscode but the folder is empty and there is no file.

obviously I can open it with right-clicking and open with code but is there a way i could open it through terminal?

I'm running Ubuntu as my operating system.

Comment: try this, it has been asked already: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244836/open-file-from-terminal-in-specific-application

Comment: I think i found the problem I typed the command wrong it should be " code . " thanks though for helping me

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to Ubuntu Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `cd` to enter in the folder that you want to open in vs code.

After that you just need to use `code .` and it will open the current folder in vs code.

Comment: If VS code is at all competently written (which is of course doubtful, given its provenance; but I still have some hope), it doesn't require you to `cd` anywhere. Just pass the name of the directory you want to add instead of `.`.